# What causes thorns to grow in FrontierVille?

Tags: frontierville

Sometimes I'm trying to discourage thorns, and sometimes I'm trying to get them to grow for quests.  Any idea what causes thorns to grow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My gf informs me that they grow underneath trees. Apparently if you move all your animals and buildings away from your pine and oak trees they'll grow. After a few days you cut down the trees and the thorns will appear. If you don't want thorns, keep animals or buildings near the trees and they shouldn't appear.

Comment: It took me a long time to figure this one out.  Your gf was mostly right.  Apparently, you have a lot more luck in the top-right corner than anywhere else.  It seems that you have to move all animals and buildings away from this area, and thin out the pine trees.  The thorns will grow back under the oak trees.